# Elastic search and Firebase: Result limit change and weird query results

Tags: javascript, android, google-app-engine, elasticsearch, firebase

I have setup an elastic search instant, created a Firebase project and run flashlight on my localhost. When I query the Firebase database in the default path (search/request) I get 10 results created in the search/response path in my database instance on Firebase.

Can someone more experienced on this please explain:

1. How can I change the result limit to more than 10 results on Firebase?
   (I tried tinkering with `SearchQueue.js`using the code in the bottom but i didn't manage to make it work.
2. Why the search results when the queries are performed **without specifying index and type** return the total number of entries on elastic server and therefore irrelevant results on Firebase?

I used postman for the ReST calls (PUT) on firebase and the JSON content was sent over to /search/request/

This json content worked in terms of results:

```
{ "index": "chatmessages", "type": "chat", "query": "georgebest"}
```

but this one did not:

```
{"query": "georgebest"}
```

Both returned a `Status: 200 OK` .

Let me add that using Sense and running the same query the results are totally correct. The issue occurs when flashlight is used.

Please note that I don't use any rules and I left the Firebase database open for testing purposes. 
Let me know if any additional information is required..Thanks.

code snippet for 1):

```
SearchQueue.prototype = {
_process: function(snap) {
 var dat = snap.val();
 var key = snap.key;

 if (this._assertValidSearch(key, dat)) {
  // Perform (a very simple) ElasticSearch query
   var searchProps = {
     index: dat.index,
     type: dat.type,
     //added variables
     size : dat.size,
     from : dat.from
           };
```

Comment: Please include some real code here. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Of particular interest would be the actual JSON your client is writing into the database to perform the search. If you've modified the code base (as you've suggested by "tinkering with SearchQueue) you should include the mods as well.

Comment: Also posted [in the issue tracker](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight/issues/101)

Comment: Sure thing,just wanted to keep minimum footprint on my post! Will re-edit asap with some code and json results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was causing the issues in my case (probably also caused via some other means as Kato suggested above).

For the first issue:
I was running a previous version of node.js in my system and what I did was to update the node.js to *version 6.9.1*  and then upgrade npm to *version 4.0.2* (using `npm install npm@latest -g` ) afterwards I reinstated all the required node_modules (`npm install --save firebase` and `npm install --save elasticsearch`)  and voila! it worked! 
The code I used for the *size* and *from* variables:

```
SearchQueue.prototype = {
_process: function(snap) {
 var dat = snap.val();
 var key = snap.key;

 if (this._assertValidSearch(key, dat)) {
  // Perform (a very simple) ElasticSearch query
   var searchProps = {
     index: dat.index,
     type: dat.type,
     //added variables
     size : dat.size,
     from : dat.from,
           };
```

The content of the json file :

```
{ "index":"chatmessages","type" : "chat", "query":"some_query", "from":"0", "size":"20"}
```

For the second issue:
The results were not passing correctly to elastic server, returning "undefined" and a hit number of all results stored.
I used postman to send the JSON in the following URL `firebase_address/search/request/some_object.json`
but just for reference if you want to do it manually in firebase, you should create something like this:
[image: firebase json structure]

Of course the way to go from here is with the [latest version](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) as suggested above!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were running into a bug [fixed in the 0.2.0 release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918041/elastic-search-and-firebase-result-limit-change-and-weird-query-results#40918041).

Note that in the latest release `query` was replaced by `q` or `body` to be inline with ES. (`query` still works for now)

A more useful sample is now included in the doc [here](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight/blob/master/README.md#example-paginate).

```
 {
   "from" : 0, 
   "size" : 50, 
   "body": {
     "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": "foo"
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Using `q` for the sql lite format also works:

```
{
   "from" : 0, 
   "size" : 50, 
   "q": "foo"
}
```